# How to create circle imageview with a transparent border?

Tags: java, android, xml, alert

I want to create an alert dialog same as shown in the image but I am stuck on how to create that center imageview with the transparent border.

[image]

Comment: Use this library [link](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog has some `View`s which resemble a `BottomAppBar` and a `FloatingActionButton`. Of course it is possible to write a custom `View` which looks just like a `BottomAppBar`, but it's easier to use the original thing.

You can use the following layout for the dialog (I left out the button bar because I think you already know you can achieve this with e.g. a `LinearLayout`):

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:backgroundTint="#0000ff"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:fabCradleMargin="4dp"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="4dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="@string/lorem_string"
    android:lines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
    app:elevation="0dp"/>
```

[image: screenshot of dialog]

For more information on styling the `BottomAppBar`, see the [developer documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/)